# In which languages is translated Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Tomorrow is starting the sale of bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition with Ubuntu Touch inside. I consider to buy it, but first I want to ask. In which languages is Ubuntu Phone localized? Is it localized into czech language?

Comment: See https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`language-pack-touch-cs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/language-pack-touch-cs) is well listed in the image [manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/ubuntu-rtm/14.09-factory/daily-preinstalled/20150209/14.09-factory-preinstalled-touch-armhf.manifest).